# 'The specified module could not be found.' in win32gui.CreateDC()

Tags: python-3.x

dc = win32gui.CreateDC(printprocessor, printerName, devmode)

It is throwing below error in this line.

2023.04.26:16.58.52Document: https://sandbox2-gcsweb.test.pb.com/usps/517575957/outbound/label/0517baf26dfd46488363b8bf7cdb451f.pdf Retrieved pointer

2023.04.26:16.58.52 Exception Type: <class 'pywintypes.error'>; (126, 'CreateDC', 'The specified module could not be found.')
2023.04.26:16.58.52 ['  File "C:\Users\004A9U744\Documents\workspace\pubsub\src\script\printerHelperWindows.py", line 1484, in CreateHandleDC\n    dc = win32gui.CreateDC(printprocessor, printerName, devmode)\n']

2023.04.26:16.58.52 ['  File "C:\Users\004A9U744\Documents\workspace\pubsub\src\script\printerHelperWindows.py", line 1484, in CreateHandleDC\n    dc = win32gui.CreateDC(printprocessor, printerName, devmode)\n']
2023.04.26:16.58.52 Exception Type: <class 'TypeError'>; cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
2023.04.26:16.58.52 ['  File "C:\Users\004A9U744\Documents\workspace\pubsub\src\script\printerManager.py", line 2116, in printUsingWindowsNew\n    hdc = printerHelper.GetPrinterHandlers(printerName, hprinter, dm, tray, orientation, driverSettings)\n', '  File "C:\Users\004A9U744\Documents\workspace\pubsub\src\script\printerHelperWindows.py", line 1475, in GetPrinterHandlers\n    _,hdc = self.CreateHandleDC(printprocessor, printerName, devmode)\n']
2023.04.26:16.58.52 error :0
2023.04.26:16.58.52 [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\004A9U744\Documents\workspace\pubsub\poppler\bin\0f4d653b-5bc6-6b2b-9a8d-acfcf9bb9de0.0.png'

Tried with reinstallation of pywin32 module, retarted windows installer but nothing worked